# Require password for iPhone to accept Gmail

Tags: gmail, iphone

How do I stop my emails coming into my iPhone automatically as opposed to having to put in my password?

Comment: Please clarify. The current wording of this question is confusing. Do you *want* it to ask for your password every time?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about requiring a password to see emails, I believe the only ways to do this are:

- Use Safari to access Gmail instead of the Email app. Then logoff after you are done using it.
- Set up a pass code lock on your iPhone. This will require a password to do anything on the phone though.
- Use some other 3rd party app which requires a password to see the email messages.